# preventing a date form element from displaying 'day', 'month', and 'year' labels?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a D7 form with a date element on it. I want it not to display 'day', 'month', and 'year' elements. I looked at `'#display_title' => FALSE` but that doesn't work.

Can I disable the display in the form definition, or must I do this elsewhere?

Comment: I did this in css: div.container-inline-date {
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the property you're looking for is [`#title_display`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#title_display), not `#display_title`. Also you wouldn't set it to `FALSE` but one of these:

- before
- after
- invisible
- attribute

In your case you'd want to set it to `invisible`:

```
$form['element']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
```

That will render the label, so your form remains accessible, but hide it from display.